# C++: Binary search tree works for integers but crashes when I try and pass strings

Tags: c++, string, templates, binary-search-tree

I posted [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223514/trying-to-adapt-binary-search-tree-for-two-parameters-getting-crash-c) yesterday, when I was continuously getting crashes on my dual parameter binary search tree.

I've since managed to get it to accept integers as parameters, however, what I really need to be able to do is use strings as the parameters, and I'm still crashing every time I do so.

I'll include the code for the insert function as well as my node class.

```
void insert (K k, V v) {
  TreeNode<K,V> * treeNode = new TreeNode<K,V> (k,v);
  TreeNode<K,V> *temp=NULL;
  TreeNode<K,V> *prev=NULL;
  temp = root;

  while(temp) { // crashes in this loop, even if I remove loop and have it only activate once
    prev = temp;
    if (temp->key < treeNode->key)  //MARKER
      temp = temp->right;           //MARKER
    else
      temp = temp->left;
  }

  if (prev==NULL)
    root = treeNode;
  else {
    if (prev->key<treeNode->key)
      prev->right = treeNode;  
    else
      prev->left = treeNode;
  }
}
```

And the node class:

```
template <class K, class V> class TreeNode {
  public:
  TreeNode(K k, V v): key(k), value(v), left(0), right(0) {}

  K       key;
  V       value;
  TreeNode<K,V>   *left;
  TreeNode<K,V>   *right;
  template <class X, class Y> friend std::ostream & operator 
  << (std::ostream &s,const TreeNode<X,Y> &t);    
};
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

AS SUGGESTED: Reduced version of the full code.

/* bst.h */

```
#ifndef __CSC116__BST_H__
#define __CSC116__BST_H__


#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

unsigned int heightCount;



template <class K, class V> class TreeNode
{
public:
TreeNode(K k, V v): key(k), value(v), left(0), right(0) {}

K       key;
V       value;
TreeNode<K,V>   *left;
TreeNode<K,V>   *right;
template <class X, class Y> friend std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream &s, 
const TreeNode<X,Y> &t);
};


// TreeNodes can output themselves to streams
template <class K, class V> std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &s, const TreeNode<K,V> &n)
{
s << "\"" << n.key << ":" << n.value << "\"";
return s;
}

class key_not_found_exception { //Currently inactive
};


template <class K, class V> class BinarySearchTree {
public:
//
// Constructor
//
BinarySearchTree ()
{
    sizeCount = 0;
}


~BinarySearchTree()
{
}


void insert (K k, V v) {
TreeNode<K,V> * treeNode = new TreeNode<K,V> (k,v);
TreeNode<K,V> *temp=NULL;
TreeNode<K,V> *prev=NULL;
temp = root;

while(temp) { // crashes in this loop, even if I remove loop and have it only activate once
prev = temp;
if (temp->key < treeNode->key)

temp = temp->right;
else
temp = temp->left;
}

if (prev==NULL)
root = treeNode;
else {
if (prev->key<treeNode->key)
  prev->right = treeNode;  
else
  prev->left = treeNode;
}

}

bool isEmpty() const
{
return root == NULL;
}


unsigned int size()
{
    cout << sizeCount;  //Currently inactive
    return 0;
}



private:

unsigned int doHeight (TreeNode<K,V> *t)  //Currently inactive
{
    return -1;
}

void        doDelete (TreeNode<K,V> * n )  
{
}

TreeNode<K,V>   *root;
unsigned int    count;
unsigned int    sizeCount;



template <class X, class Y> friend class tree_view; 
template <class X, class Y> friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &s, const
BinarySearchTree<X,Y> &t);
};

template <class K,class V> void do_inorder (std::ostream &s, const TreeNode<K,V> *n)
{
if (!n)
    return;
do_inorder(s,n->left);
s << n->key << ":" << n->value << " ";
do_inorder(s,n->right);
}


// Output the tree to a stream by doing an in-order traversal

template <class K, class V> std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &s, const    
BinarySearchTree<K,V> &t)
{
s << "{ ";
do_inorder(s,t.root);
s << "}";
return s;
}
#endif
```

/*bst_tester.cpp*/

```
// bst_tester.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "bst.h"
#include "tree_view.h"

using namespace std;



class bst_tester_exception
{
public:
    bst_tester_exception (const string & msg, unsigned int line) : _msg(msg), _line(line) {}
    string what() const 
    { 
        ostringstream s;
        s << _line;

        return _msg + " line number: " + s.str(); 
    }
private:
    bst_tester_exception();
    string _msg;
    unsigned int _line;
};



void test_insert_size_height()
{
BinarySearchTree<string,string> t;

if (t.height() != 0)
    throw bst_tester_exception(__func__,__LINE__);

if (t.size() != 0 )
    throw bst_tester_exception(__func__,__LINE__);


t.insert("bob", "bobdata");
t.insert("abe", "abedata");
t.insert("jane", "janedata");

if (t.height() != 2)
    throw bst_tester_exception(__func__,__LINE__);

if (t.size() != 3 )
    throw bst_tester_exception(__func__,__LINE__);


}




int main ()
{
unsigned int tests_passed = 0;

try
{
    test_insert_size_height();
    tests_passed++;



}
catch (bst_tester_exception &e)
{
    cout << "Failed test case: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
catch (...)
{
    cout << "Caught unhandled exception." << std::endl;
}
cout << "Passed: " << tests_passed << endl;

return tests_passed;
}
```

Comment: The code that uses the class would be relevant.

Comment: You *are* using an `std::string`, not a `char` pointer, right?

Comment: `Crashes in this loop, even if I remove loop and have it only activate once`  That doesn't mean that this is where the problem is.  The problem could have originated in code before this line is executed.

Comment: Sure, the instruction that causes the crash is t.insert("bob", "bobdata");

Comment: Paul: I've isolated the problem to this area by commenting out lines. I'm pretty much positive it takes place somewhere in here.

Comment: Use a debugger. Explore the variables at the point of crash. Look for null pointers, out of range access, etc. Determine the cause. rince, repeat.

Comment: nvoigt: as far as I know, yes, they are true strings.

Comment: Okay, so I guess this is my really big question: am I doing anything illegal here? It compiles just fine, but really, really doesn't seem to want to accept a string. Just eyeballing it, does it look like this should work?

Comment: Usually the lower value is on the left, not the right.  Having it the other way should work, but you have to be certain you're consistent.  Other than that the code is fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a93abebaf8b2ebf3

Comment: "am I doing anything illegal here?" No one knows. You are not showing all of your code.

Comment: What other relevant parts would be useful? I figured this was the extent of what people would want to see, but I can certainly provide more.

Comment: Okay, I've narrowed it down a bit more. The two lines: "if (temp->key < treeNode->key)" and "temp = temp->right;" are both causing crashes, whereas the program will run if they're commented out. Does that help anything? I've added markers to the code.

Comment: Perhaps `temp` contains a value that is not a valid pointer to a `treeNode`... Are you certain that your leaf nodes have proper NULL values in their left/right pointers? Printing the pointer values as you walk the tree might be enlightening...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by proper NULL values in the left and right pointers? I do have the line "TreeNode(K k, V v): key(k), value(v), left(0), right(0) {}" in the TreeNode template, is that what you're referring to?

Comment: If in doubt, show it all. If all of it is too much, your job is to reduce it such that it still compiles and shows the behaviour in question (not to throw away some lines you deem irrelevant). You were advised to show code that uses the class. Ignore it at your peril.

Comment: Alright, I'll update the code to include more.

Comment: @Mock - What you posted are two perfectly valid lines of code.  We have no context as to when, where, or how those lines of code are used in your program.   Also, when you corrupt memory in any part of your program, then other parts of your program may fail.  What you posted is where the program finally breaks down, and more than likely *not* the origin of the issue.  What if you've messed up `root` in some way?  We don't know by looking at that code.  The only complete example we have is what MooingDuck posted.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the post to show a reduced version of the full code.

Comment: Your reduced version does not compile because there is no `"bst.h"`. Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: n.m. - The code I added is broken into two parts. The first one (so third section overall) is bst.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize `root` in your binary search tree, so when you go into `insert` the first time, `root` is not set to NULL like it should be.  If it "works" for integers, you were probably just getting lucky in some way.

Comment: Ha! I think that just might have done it. I added "root = NULL" to the Constructor and it's not crashing! I built a quick test code to test out integers, when I carried it over I forgot to add the line because it's not in the insert function. I'm going to play with it but I think that might have been my problem, thank you so much, and to everyone else who helped out!